# Add pattern/decals to maps on echarts for single series

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to achieve a world map with countries colored by a certain value, however, I also need to make it aria compliant, meaning that I will need to either add a pattern or decals to these fill colors.

I tried enabling aria support, but it applies the same decal for every country, I also tried changing the item style with the decal property, but no luck.

Is there any way to add pattern/decals to these fill colors? As to have, have some dashed, others filled, and other with circles for example.

```
  aria: {
        series: 'single',
        decal: {
          show: true
        }
      },

// OR Inside item style
decal: {
    color: 'blue',
    dashArrayX: [1, 0],
    dashArrayY: [2, 5],
    symbolSize: 1,
    rotation: Math.PI / 6
  },
```

Here is the code pen:

https://codepen.io/Caio-Oliveira-the-looper/pen/ZEqMvXe?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Try out `itemStyle.decal` in data:
[See Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack&code=CYUwxghgNgzgBAXjgbQFBzgbzqSUBcW6GcYA9lGQE6EDkA5lSCAHa0A0xGwEMAFgEEqVCAE8AGoWQBGdnAAMAXU4kcvQcLEBNKQCY5AVmVc4MUQFsARhQDKASwBeIQrJNUyAFwge7ZFoQBZbz4AOgAFAEk4AHo4ADZiAF9ElSwccGhCTBNySho4WiZgDhMzKwo6MDsqMCgQEtUefiERCSkTDGQADjku41VO-V7hhUUTfpImjVadFDi5JVSMMusoeydCeRCupJTibFxMolVLCDAAa0YyAFcWYABhCmo6AAc7FnOGklzngssoa71JamCyrOjAOwQcx-YrAla2RzOODSXapA4ZAjHb5PfIAIio9FOAAohgoFgsQgYAJS44FTFpiSRwIm6KnIImyBRUibcdQM0SzFlslmGbnA9xeHx-TaU3QAZgMAE4ugB2FUGJVdXTKnqlUEVOD48AeWl68prREuVLJVCKADcqFQZBeUpYiCxECokKyJlYEH-IGAhA8VEBcJAXpAMDoMHe9DqX24GJ9A1MfDIAHdg6GQHIOuk8NGUPmMNlU6ofvkGExWIny_TNG0UJzFiXJnzG7NkPo4EZgan4RaNsj-wMJd5fP44EEPKFIjF4m29uWsSvK3QinWB_rMbQqjUE6PGh3Wky0CvVN1ejyL8hST04A-lG2MDfUw2ZlJ5qMjyRB-skS2HYV0SfMxlUUCMGXOBTguK5bgeHE6AAYhAeQADMDHQoFiBgCM7CjdpVDLAYPFEF4kVocwIBeLc4Gol46AzagoFhfN3ChbMw3zPC6jADxAwCMhQBjOND3zEBzBePheDsIsSNTOwBPMGwyLqFML2iWJHjyOB3jgSTpNk-AYElEAQhfOBPRACAdN-QpA1oJd82g48vCI8tsBYKFKIAIREBw7CgDg4AAN2gQErT05TVNEdSC2gGA70UOBXIGLyfLoAAla4YFjCAQvCgEkR7JTJNi-LDlgGQUrS4i4G88xKIAGTsSxRAKuQisikdovKtSkSqpK5Vq38MqaugAFF6HIjxCoipE5VSsaGsygoBFykNoEhebisIAAWOQypUgbCCG7tarA0deONDTFJi07V3LdcCmQ-R3rok5qFAKg7KrN6Pt_DBrCoH6AHU7GAWcXEpIGrKYWykIKF5rioF5xIveGbIqpEFIvF7aBRtGE0syDyzJiDR2OnG7oGAmAfkT6YO-iM_pQuUOaZkHwch6GFFhttrMRvJKmoFhYygT5fyFmmntTAnGDEJyQJckwyYmUK5OuaAgkYp7zHeTZgWogAPA7gTwMBrigf14pDbjVDqdCPA3Ox6D4ObgQALXeLKIBYehcfzF7kFoN65UVaQsJC2h_kBGPkPQpP5EVRUE_QxUwEgAxaHAkgydAxI7SAA)
[image: map]